# How can I store a table in a variable with each row as an element and a delimiter to distinguish columns using BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to store an html table in a variable called store.

```
html = ['<html><body><p align="center"><table><tr><td>row1col1</td><td>row1col2</td><td>row1col3</td></tr><tr><td>row2col1</td><td>row2col2</td><td>row2col3</td></tr></table></html>']
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(html))
table = soup.find('table')
rows = table.findAll('tr')

store = []
row = []
numcols = []

for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    for td in cols:
        try:
            text = ''.join(td.find(text=True))
        except Exception:
            text = ''
        text = text+"|"
        row.append(text)
    store = ''.join(row)
print store
```

The following is output:

```
row1col1|row1col2|row1col3|row2col1|row2col2|row2col3|
```

I would like to store the rows separately in the "store" variable so that I have each row in one element of "store" with a | symbol separating each column.  Right now, there is no way to distinguish which items go in which row.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

My guess it that you're after something like this:

```
html = '<html><body><p align="center"><table><tr><td>row1col1</td><td>row1col2</td><td>row1col3</td></tr><tr><td>row2col1</td><td>row2col2</td><td>row2col3</td></tr></table></html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table = soup.find('table')
rows = table.findAll('tr')

store = []

for tr in rows:
  cols = tr.findAll('td')
  row = []
  for td in cols:
    try:
      row.append(''.join(td.find(text=True)))
    except Exception:
      row.append('')
  store.append('|'.join(row))

print '\n'.join(store)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response.  Worked perfectly.

Comment: I will as soon as I get a high enough reputation.  Right now, I am not allowed to vote since I'm new to stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Josh Lee: Glad it worked -- I don't have beautifulsoup installed so the answer was actually untested ;) @senderle: Thanks :)